# The webView cannot fill parent in Android Studio

Tags: android, webview

[image]
[image]
Here is still some blank space between the screen and webView.
How can I solve it?
I want the webView occupy the full screen without any blank space.
Thank you!

Comment: can you post the xml layout

Comment: You need to post the XML and describe your problem with more clarity

Comment: ... **as TEXT**, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all padding from main layout Relative layout.